# Trying to perform union when columns dont match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fetch records from temporary and permaenent  tables using UNION .
Table 1 - Cust Permanent

```
cid       marital_status  profession   gender   mobile        current_status      temp_id
 1              1             6            Male      984343435          1                1
```

table 2 - cust temp

```
cid        marital_status        gender   mobile        current_status      perm_id
 1             1                  Male         984343435         1                1
```

Also, trying to perform join from masters to fetch decription according to id. Performing a  union query to fetch all records from permanent table, problem i'm facing is temp table will not have profession, but permanent table has and for union to work columns count should be same.
Query i tried as a work around :

```
select cid,ma.master.desc, pr_master.desc,gender,mobile,current_status from cust_permament
left join ma_master on ma_master.id = cust_permament.marital_status
left join pr_master on pr_master.id = cust_permament.profession
UNION

select cid,ma.master.desc as marital_status, '' desc,gender,mobile,current_status from cust_temp
left join ma_master on ma_master.id = cust_temp.marital_status
```

This returns 2 rows one with empty profession and other with profession from permanent table.
BUt i need single record with profession from permamnet table

Expected result

```
cid         desc         desc      gender      mobile          current_status
1            Single      Teacher      Male         984343435          1
```

Actual Output

```
cid         desc         desc      gender      mobile          current_status
1            Single      Teacher      Male         984343435          1
1            Single                   Male         984343435          1
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: need single record instead of 2

Comment: `UNION` merges tables row wise, `JOIN` merges tables column-wise.

I cannot understand what you're trying to achieve, can you include desired output as an example?

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: in the second query use `NULL as profession`

Comment: @Squirrel that didnt work. Returns 2 rows

Comment: Then you should not be using a `UNION`. Your requirement is unclear. Perhaps you should be using a `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to unite as one row if all rows except profession is same.

So I suggest you to use group all column except profession to your result as following.

I renamed second column as profession to prevent duplicated column name, and replaced `**'' desc**` to `null as profession` to use in min function.

You can use `max` instead of `min` since it's purpose is to remove null.

```sql
with t as
(
select ma_master.desc, pr_master.desc as profession, gender, mobile, current_status from cust_permament
left join ma_master on ma_master.id = cust_permament.marital_status
left join pr_master on pr_master.id = cust_permament.profession
UNION

select ma_master.desc, null as profession, gender, mobile, current_status from cust_temp
left join ma_master on ma_master.id = cust_temp.marital_status
)
select desc, min(profession) as profession, gender, mobile, current_status from cust_permament
from   t
group by desc, gender, mobile, current_status
```